# Compare Time.now in Rails but ignore year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date, activerecord, time

I have the following code in my Rails 3 application:

```
  scope :active, lambda {
    where("starts_at <= ? AND ends_at >= ?", Time.now.utc, Time.now.utc)
  }
  scope :since, lambda { |hide_time|
    where("updated_at > ? OR starts_at > ?", hide_time.utc, hide_time.utc) if hide_time
  }

  def self.display(hide_time)
    active.since(hide_time)
  end
```

However, I want to return the results regardless of whether the year matches the current year or not. So long as the day and month match it's fine. Is this possible?

The `starts_at` and `ends_at` columns are `datetime` formatted. So they will automatically include a year even if I dont set one in the form:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :starts_at, :order => [:day, :month], :discard_year => true %>
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Might have to do straight SQL for this one.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I presume that means the database type? If so, mySQL

Comment: The solution depends on how you want to handle February 29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Old Pro points out in the comments this does pose a problem with leap years.  You likely want to split each dayofyear into MONTH(x) AND DAYOFMONTH(x) instead.

---

You can use the dayofyear function
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear

```
scope :active, lambda {
    where("dayofyear(starts_at) <= dayofyear(?) AND 
      dayofyear(ends_at) >= dayofyear(?)", Time.now.utc, Time.now.utc)
  }
  scope :since, lambda { |hide_time|
    where("dayofyear(updated_at) > dayofyear(?) OR 
      dayofyear(starts_at) > dayofyear(?)", hide_time.utc, hide_time.utc) if hide_time
  }
```

in [mssql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) it's

> datepart(dayofyear,date)

in [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html) it's

> extract(DOY from date)

in [sqlite3](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions) it's

> strftime("%j",date)

Comment: @dannymcc Note that this will fail (according to the OPs stated goal) when comparing a date after Feb 28 in a leap year with a date in a non-leap year.  This code will have 1-MAR-2000 == 2-MAR-2001.