# How to select rows covering today's day and month in pg / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg

So I have this table called SeasonRate

```
create_table "season_rates", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.datetime "from_date"
  t.datetime "to_date"
  t.float    "rate"
  t.integer  "property_type_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
  t.index ["property_type_id"], name: "index_season_rates_on_property_type_id", using: :btree
end
```

I want to be able to find the row in which today's date falls in between `from_date` and `to_date` ignoring the year. So far, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357033/compare-time-now-in-rails-but-ignore-year) I have been able to write this code

```
def todays_rate(apartment)
  property_type = apartment.property_type_id
  @rate = SeasonRate.where(property_type_id: property_type)
  @todays_rate = @rate.where("extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP from_date) <= extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP ?) AND extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP to_date) >= extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP ?)",Date.today, Date.today)
end
```

But it gives me error saying

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from_date"
>       LINE 1: ...ty_type_id" = $1 AND (extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP from_date)...
>                                                                ^
>       : SELECT "season_rates".* FROM "season_rates" WHERE "season_rates"."property_type_id" = $1 AND (extract (DOY FROM
>   TIMESTAMP from_date) <= extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP '2017-08-04') AND
>   extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP to_date) >= extract (DOY FROM TIMESTAMP
>   '2017-08-04'))

I have searched for this problem alot but I could not find any solution. Please help me what am I doing wrong here or if you have better solution for this problem, it'd be great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it looks like adding `TIMESTAMP` is telling Postgres to convert a string into a timestamp, and then you aren't giving it a string, you're giving it a column name, thus a syntax error:

```
select EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP created_at), created_at from users;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "created_at"
LINE 1: select EXTRACT(DOY FROM TIMESTAMP created_at), created_at fr...
```

but you can just give it the column name instead of a string to convert and it seems to work fine

```
select EXTRACT(DOY FROM created_at), created_at from users;
date_part |         created_at
-----------+----------------------------
       190 | 2017-07-09 21:07:41.746157
```

Comment: I tried that too but removing timestamp gives me this error
 `PG::AmbiguousFunction: ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: ...ype_id" = $1 AND (extract (DOY FROM from_date) <= extract (D...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: hmm, did you try `extract (DOY FROM from_date::date)` or `extract (DOY FROM from_date::timestamp)`, that error seems like it doesn't know exactly what that column type is? I receive that error when I try to run it on a non-date (or timestamp) column, even if it's in a date format. For instance `select EXTRACT(DOY FROM first_name::timestamp), created_at from users;` threw the error until I added `::timestamp` (and then it threw different ones until I changed everyones first name to '2017-08-04')